# I2C chip not showing up

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, gpio

Recently I bought a Raspberry Pi (Model B 512MB, Raspbian Wheezy) and three sensors.
I successfully programmed the first sensor.

But now I did something horrible, I accidentally connected the ground of my BMP085 sensor to the 5V pin on the Raspberry. All the other pins where connected correctly.

I'm now wondering how I can see if I broke the sensor or the gpio. When I try 
`i2cdetect -y 1` it only gives me `--`. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You've reverse-biased the BMP085 with about -1.7V (3.3V – 5V). This has almost certainly destroyed it, and may have caused collateral damage other devices on the bus as well, potentially including the host rPi.

It's impossible for us to determine what may have happened without some hands-on troubleshooting. You will probably want to start by removing the destroyed BMP085 and seeing if the other I2C devices work on their own. If not, you will probably need to use a logic analyzer or oscilloscope to determine if the rPi I2C output is still working.